# How can I make an exception to an htaccess redirect that applies to all paths on a site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a little website that use this htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum/$1 [L]
```

Basically every URI requested from `mysite.it` gets redirected to `mysite.it/forum`.

I made another website on the same dir level as "forum", called "rss".

```
Root/
    ->forum/
    ->rss/
```

I want to add another rule so that if I open `mysite.it/rss` the htaccess rules doesn't redirect me to `mysite.it/forum/rss`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have other files in the root you simply don't want to allow access to, while forwarding most requests into `forum/` the simplest modification you can make is to change the exclusion pattern to match *either* forum or rss with an `or` group `(a|b)`. You can continue to add other patterns inside the group with `|` as it becomes necessary.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the URI matches neither forum no rss...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(forum|rss)
# rewrite.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum/$1 [L]
```

This allows you redirect to forum only if file or directory doesn't exists.